# Rewriting Exner function

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, approximation

I have this function that I am working with - [Exner function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exner_function)

$$  \left(\frac{p}{p_0}\right)^\frac{R_d}{c_p} = \frac{T}{\theta} $$

and I am trying to solve for theta numerically

So

$$  \theta = T \,\cdot\, p_0^\frac{R_d}{C_p} \, \cdot\frac{1}{p^\frac{R_d}{C_p}}$$

In a numerical software that I am looking at they have approximated

$$ \frac{1}{p^\frac{R_d}{C_p}}$$

as 
    $$ -\frac{R_d}{C_p} \cdot p$$

Since there is no documentation my first reaction was to assume that approximation was obtained used a Taylor series expansion (up to first order)

I am assuming they did they did a Taylor series expansion of the following expression

$$ \frac{1}{x^n} $$

It is still not exactly equal to that but it is close. Am I on the right track ?

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote $$\left(\frac{p}{p_0}\right)^a=\frac{T}{\theta }\implies \theta =T \left(\frac{p}{p_0}\right)^{-a}$$

Now, use Taylor series around $p=p_0$ to get 
$$\theta=T-\frac{a T }{p}(p-p_0)+O\left((p-p_0)^2\right)=(1+a)T-\frac{a  T}{p_0}p+O\left((p-p_0)^2\right)$$